# How helpful is it to edit old posts with styling and spelling variations?

Tags: discussion, editing

Do we really need to add random *italics* or **bolds** to questions years after any activity? Or shuffle `-` from one word to another? I feel like we've been seeing this a lot (relative to the usual inactivity, perhaps) lately. And in my opinion, the benefits of such edits seem too dubious to be worth bumping old questions (and thereby causing new posts to sink). Has anyone else thought about this?

Comment: Do we need these changes? Probably not. However, SE encourages this kind of activity with at least 5 badges awarded for editing, two of which [Excavator](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/excavator) and [Archaeologist](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/archaeologist) are aimed purely at editing old questions.

Comment: @SteveBird I'm not sure changes like adding bold or italics or changing war-weary to war weary is what they had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I think we had a discussion in chat about this a few years back.

I'm the kind of person who likes to tweak things. Writing is never finished, just abandoned.

The issue many people have with late minor edits is that it artificially "bumps" old questions on the active question list. The worst part about this is that someone could use it to game the system by just making pointless edits every time their favorite question drops too low. But even at best, the entire question is nowhere near materially changed enough to warrant being bumped to the front page just because a typo was fixed.

I can understand that, and perfectionists like me should come to understand it too.

The compromise I have come to is to not fix up old posts *until activity has bumped them anyway*.

In the meantime, I'd suggest that for users who really aren't interested in revisiting any old questions, hit the "Questions" link at the top of your browser, and then make sure the tab link under there is set to "new". That's how I prefer to hit this stack. New questions are much more likely to be helped by your input as a user than "active" ones<sup>*</sup>.

You could even go so far as to make https://history.stackexchange.com/questions your entry link into this stack.

<sup>* - As a **moderator** however, active questions are quite likely to need a look-over.</sup>

Comment: Well, yes, I am talking about when its bumping up old questions, sometimes with completely or almost completely superfluous changes. I have no problems with fixing up questions when they rise to the front.